# Weird definition of discrete random variable

Tags: random-variables

My textbook, *Introduction to Probability* by Blitzstein and Hwang, gives the following definition of a discrete random variable (p. 94):

> A random variable $X$ is said to be *discrete* if there is a finite list of values $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ or an infinite list of values $a_1, a_2, \dots$ such that $P(X = a_j \ \text{for some $j$}) = 1$.

Initially, this definition seemed a bit weird to me. It's saying that a random variable $X$ is said to be discrete if the probability of the random variable being equal to some outcome $a_j$ in the sample space for any $j$ is equal to $1$; in other words, that it is certain that some outcome will occur. But would I be correct in presuming that what the author is likely attempting to accomplish by defining a discrete random variable in this way is to contrast it with the definition of a *continuous* random variable, since the case of a continuous random variable is one in which the probability that the random variable is equal to any outcome in the sample space is equal to $0$?

Comment: Maybe it would have been more clear if the textbook had said $P(X \in \{a_1, a_2, \ldots \}) = 1$.

Comment: @littleO, definitely, but are they the same thing? I mean $P(X = a_j$ for some $j)$ and $P(X \in \{a_1, a_2, ... \})$ ? They don't seem same to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of what the author is doing is incorrect. A priori, a random variable $X$ is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ into the real numbers $\mathbb R$. The author is saying that, even though the function could take any real value, there is a distinguished finite set of values that it takes with probability $1$. This means that the set $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ has the property that the event
$$
\bigl\{\omega\in\Omega\colon X(\omega)\in \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}\bigr\}
$$
is assigned a probability of $1$.

For example, you can consider the sample space $\Omega=\{0,1\}$ with equal probability assigned to each of the two values (i.e., flipping a fair coin). Then we have a random variable $X\colon \{0,1\}\to\mathbb R$ given by setting $X(0)=\pi$ and $X(1)=e$, for example. It satisfies the author's definition since one can choose $\{a_1,a_2\}=\{\pi,e\}$ and then the probability assigned to the event $\{\omega\colon X(w)\in \{\pi,e\}\}$ is $1$, even though there are other choices of $a_i$ such that the probability is either $0$ or $\tfrac 12$. For the definition to work, there just needs to be *some* set of finite values that captures all of the probability.

By the way, this definition should more accurately be called "finite range", since it does not cover some extremely famous examples of discrete random variables like a geometric random variable, for instance.

Comment: What would these other choices of $a_i$ be such that their probability is either 0 or $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @IusKlesar for instance, if $\{a_1,a_2\}=\{1,2\}$ then the probability is $0$, whereas if $\{a_1,a_2\}=\{\pi,e+1\}$ then the probability is $\tfrac12$.

Comment: Your explanations clearly describes what is the discrete random variable, but I don't see that it is the same as the original definition in the question. For me the definition clearly states that there should be some value $a_j$ in the list for which $X$ takes this value with probability $1$. In other words there should be some event (probably different from sample space) with probability `1` to occur. I  believe I am missing something while parsing the definition, but can't find what exactly.